# JMS Connection Pooling with Websphere MQ 7.0 in Java Standalone application

Tags: connection, jms, connection-pooling, pool

I'll be developing stand-alone Java application being JMS client. I want to make sure that every time I send a message to a queue, I do not have to create session, connection etc.

I was thinking of using CachedConnectionFactory which comes with Apache Camel or using the solution Spring provides. Still, as far as I know the limitation of the former is that it is not suitable for transactions, and of the latter, that it may not behave correctly in case of failover.

On one post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922339/how-to-pooling-the-jms-connection-in-a-standalone-java-applications) it was suggested to use Apache commons pool component, but I don't think creating such pool would be a trivial task anyway

Any comments on that?