# Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I'm using camel and spring to create a jms application (out of JEE container) to produce jms messages to send to jms provider (IBM MQ on other machine). Receiver of the messages is a non jms application.
I'm trying to move to CachingConnectionFactory on spring configuration but when doing if I'm getting a WARN :

```
15:05:51,838 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] (Camel (xxxInputCamelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[DEV.KP.xxx.yyy.R) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'DEV.KP.xxx.yyy.R' - trying to recover. Cause: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84 cannot be cast to com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession
```

Can you please help me to understand what is the meaning of the WARN and does it mean I can not or misusing CachingConnectionFactory?

Comment: ok I see now that the WARN come from one of my JmsConsumer not a JmsProducer. 
This is probably because I'm using same spring jmsConfig for consumers and producers. Is this right ? does this WARN will effect this consumer ?

Comment: Please refer to this thread which discusses the same issue :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086014/how-to-configure-spring-jms-connection-pool-for-wmq

Comment: thank you ! I see over there :" I resolved my class cast issue, it was in my DestinationResolver that casts it, but with cached pool it was getting a proxy. I updated the code in destination resolver and the pool was created" . Do you know what is the code change in DestinationResolver ?