# IBM MQSeries connection pooling with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ibm-mq

We are trying to set up a jms connection from tomcat toward IBM MQSeries, with the concern to make connection pooling.

We have followed the link below, with the solution suggested :

[WebSphere MQ connection pooling with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761793/websphere-mq-connection-pooling-with-tomcat)

I don't know how we can manage the different jms connections with the method suggested, we have made tests, and we have noticed that CachingConnectionFactory manage different jms session and not jms connection.

I share with you the link below, in which it is explained that CachingConnectionFactory does not allow to manage different jms connection but just jms sessions !

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13586

I also share with you , both files context.xml (datasource and services.xml (spring services file)

**context.xml**

```
<Resource name="jms/AN8.NOTI.MOBILE.01" auth="Container" type="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" 
    factory="com.cl.fwk.jms.utilities.RSFCachingMQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory" 
    description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages" HOST="**********" 
    PORT="****" CHAN="******" TRAN="*" QMGR="***" />

<Resource name="jms/MQAN8.NOTI.MOBILE.01" auth="Container"
    type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
    description="JMS Queue for receiving messages from Dialog" QU="********" />
```

**services.xml**

```
<!-- Ressource JNDI pour la connexion MQSeries-->
<bean id="xxxx.jmsRefConnectionFactory.mqseries" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/AN8.NOTI.MOBILE.01" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Ressource JNDI pour la file d'attente du broker MQSeries-->
<bean id="xxxx.jmsRefQueue.mqseries" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/MQAN8.NOTI.MOBILE.01" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
<!-- A cached connection to wrap the MQSeries connection -->
<bean id="xxxx.jmsConnectionFactory.mqseries" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="xxxx.jmsRefConnectionFactory.mqseries" /> -->
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="xxxx.jmsRefConnectionFactory.mqseries"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="xxxx.jmsDestinationResolver.amq" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />

<bean id="xxxx.jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="xxxx.jmsConnectionFactory.mqseries" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="xxxx.jmsRefQueue.mqseries" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="xxxx.jmsDestinationResolver.amq" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="#{T(javax.jms.Session).AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE}" />
</bean>
```

Best regards.

Comment: no there aren't mix between ActiveMq and IBM MQ in my question.

tomcat has a built-in JDBC connection pooling, but unfortunately no built-in JMS connection pooling. We try

Comment: You are right, but it was just write mistake.

I just corrected the names of beans.

like i said i want to be able manage the pool connexion jms.

CachingConnectionFactory able to maintain only 1 TCP connection under the hood, We want to manage pool multiple TCP connection with multiple session/consumer/producers under that, which is necessary for  high load system.

Comment: The jars we use are below :  mq-7.0.0.jar, mqjms-7.0.0.jar

Comment: The jars we use are below : mq-7.0.0.jar, mqjms-7.0.0.jar

Comment: The sessions work for me, but we are limtited by one connection jms connection, which means we are limited by 10 sessions.Beaucse i think each jms connection provide just 10 sessions. Below the content of MANIFEST.MF both jar mq-7.0.0.jar and  mqjms-7.0.0.jar :                                      Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service  
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.  
Specification-Version: 1.1  
Implementation-Version: 6.0.2.11 - j600-211-110318  

Specification-Version: 6.0.2.11  
Implementation-Version: 6.0.2.11 - j600-211-110318

Comment: Our version of IBM MQ is 8, and the value of parameter SVRCONN  is 10.

Comment: I have not the specific version because i am not administrator system
I have the values of both parameters MAXINST and MAXINSTC :
MAXINST  = 9 
MAXINSTC = 9

I reminding you that we are on an Tomcat server, and we don't able to create more thant one connexion through the factory com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory .

Comment: if i understand you, each SESSION JMS create a TCP/IP connection to the queue manager ? –

Comment: Did my answer help provide the information you needed to clarify the behavior you see currently and possible ways to resolve the issues you are having? If so an accept would be appreciated.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**

You need to either upgrade to a later version of the MQ classes for JMS or have your MQ admin increase the MAXINST/MAXINSTC settings to allow more channel instances.

Note the version you are using has been out of support since 2012 so I would recommend upgrading.

```
Product        Version  Release      End of Service
============   =======  ==========   =================
Websphere MQ   6.0      2005-06-24   2012-09-30
```

---

**BACKGROUND INFO FROM COMMENTS**

Based on what you provided in comments the following information is known about your current setup:

```
IBM MQ Server version: 8.0.0.? (specific maintenance level unknown)
IBM MQ jar names: mq-7.0.0.jar and mqjms-7.0.0.jar
IBM MQ jar version: 6.0.2.11
SVRCONN Channel settings: SHARECNV(10) MAXINST(9) MAXINSTC(9)
```

**Note that even though the jar files have names that contain the string 7.0.0, they are actually from IBM MQ v6.0.2.11 (technically it was called Websphere MQ at that time).**

---

The other StackOveflow question "[WebSphere MQ connection pooling with Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761793/websphere-mq-connection-pooling-with-tomcat)" you point to is referencing the fact that the IBM MQ prior to v7.0 (for example v6.0) provided connection pooling, but this was removed at MQ v7.0, and was asking how to get similar functionality at v7.0 and later.

---

The v6 connection pooling was the default in MQ v6.0 JMS as described on page 504 of the "[WebSphere MQ Using Java Version 6.0](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/csqzaw13.pdf)" manual:

> **setUseConnectionPooling**
>
> `public void setUseConnectionPooling(boolean usePooling);`
>
> Chooses whether to use connection pooling. If you set this to true,
>   JMS enables connection pooling for the lifetime of any connections
>   created through the ConnectionFactory. This also affects connections
>   created with usePooling set to false; to disable connection pooling
>   throughout a JVM, ensure that all ConnectionFactories used within the
>   JVM have usePooling set to false.

---

In the fact that the connection pooling was removed in MQ v7 is documented in the IBM MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page [Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java Platform, Enterprise Edition applications>Using IBM MQ classes for JMS>IBM MQ classes for JMS>Class MQConnectionFactory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html#setUseConnectionPooling(boolean))

> **setUseConnectionPooling**
>
> `public void setUseConnectionPooling(boolean usePooling)`
>
> ***Deprecated. JMS does not use connection pooling anymore.*** Any connection pooling
>   should be done using the facilities provided by the App Server. Set the use of
>   ConnectionPooling in earlier versions of the WebSphere MQ classes for
>   JMS. ***This method is retained for compatibility with older MQJMS
>   applications, but, because this Connection Pooling functionality has
>   been removed from version 7, setting this property will have no
>   effect.***

---

To explain the behavior you see today you also need to to know about MQ Client channel shared conversations behavior that was added in MQ v7.0, you can read about this in the IBM MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page [Migrating and upgrading>Introduction to IBM MQ migration>Coexistence, compatibility, and interoperability>MQI client: Default behavior of client-connection and server-connection channels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q001660_.htm).  Quoting a few specifics below:

> In Version 7.0 the default settings for client and server connection
>   channels changed to use shared conversations. This change affects the
>   behavior of heartbeats and channels exits, and can have an impact on
>   performance.
>
> Before Version 7.0, each conversation was allocated to a different
>   channel instance. From Version 7.0, the default for client and server
>   connections is to share an MQI channel. You use the SHARECNV (sharing
>   conversations) parameter to specify the maximum number of
>   conversations that can be shared over a particular TCP/IP client
>   channel instance. The possible values are as follows:
>
> **SHARECNV(0)**
>
> - ***This value specifies no sharing of conversations over a TCP/IP socket. The channel instance behaves exactly as if it was a Version
>     6.0 server or client connection channel***, and you do not get the extra features such as bi-directional heartbeats that are available when you
>     set SHARECNV to 1 or greater. Only use a value of 0 if you have
>     existing client applications that do not run correctly when you set
>     SHARECNV to 1 or greater.

---

Putting this all together, you have a SVRCONN channel  with the following settings:

- `SHARECNV(10)`
- `MAXINST(9)`
- `MAXINSTC(9)`

These settings when used with a MQ v7.0 and later client would mean that you could have 9 channel instances (TCP connections) between the client and queue manager and each of those could have 10 shared conversations for a total max of 90 conversations.

Because you are using MQ v6.0 classes for JMS the channel is operating as if the setting were:

- **`SHARECNV(0)`**
- `MAXINST(9)`
- `MAXINSTC(9)`

This means that can have 9 channel instances (TCP connections) between the client and the queue manager and each of those supports only a single conversation.

At MQ v6.0 classes for JMS each underlying JMS connection and every JMS session that is created on top of the JMS connection will allocate a channel instance to the queue manager.

---

To understand more about how connection and sessions interact with each other and with the SHARECNV setting look at the IBM MQ v8.0 Knowledge Center page [Developing applications>Developing JMS and Java Platform, Enterprise Edition applications>Using IBM MQ classes for JMS>Writing IBM MQ classes for JMS applications>Accessing IBM MQ features>Sharing a TCP/IP connection in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032530_.htm):

> Every JMS connection and JMS session that is created by a JMS application creates its own conversation with the queue manager.

In your case because you are using MQ v6.0 classes for JMS each "conversation" is a MQ channel instance (TCP connection) to the queue manager.

---

I would recommend you get a current IBM MQ classes for Java version to use, this would then allow you to have up to 90 shared conversations.  If contention is an issue you would need to have your MQ admin increase the `MAXINST`/`MAXINSTC` settings and decrease `SHARECNV`.

For **IBM MQ Classes for JMS** you can find the list of files required on the IBM MQ v9 Knowledge Center page "[What is installed for IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031540_.htm)":

> **Relocatable JAR files**
>   Within an enterprise, the following files can be moved to systems that need to run IBM MQ classes for JMS:
>
> - com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
> - com.ibm.mq.traceControl.jar
> - jms.jar
> - fscontext.jar
> - providerutil.jar
> - The Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jars
>
> The fscontext.jar and providerutil.jar files are required if your application performs JNDI lookups using a file system context.
>
> The Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jar files are required. For more information, see Support for non-IBM JREs.

Note that only `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`, `jms.jar`, and the Bouncy Castle security provider and CMS support jars are included in the Redistributable client, but all are included in Java All client.  You are also running 9.0.0.0 and I would recommend you go to 9.0.0.5.  You can find both the Redistributable and Java All clients on [Fix Central](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=9.0&platform=All&function=textSearch&text=Java).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. I am struggling with same issue at the moment. I have a very high performant application and we are currently using springs cachignconnetionfactory along with the right MQ settings but still not good enough. Is there a way I can implement a connection pool so that the application has multiple connections to queue manager etc?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are attempting to resolve?  Is the performance a issue? Are you hitting a channel limit in the queue manager?

Comment: So, the problem is its a really high load application (in 1000 requests per second) with really low SLA. So, it is a performance issue. We are at the channel limit. So wanted to explore if there is a way to implement connection pool and have parallel connections into it rather than using a single connection with cached sessions.

Comment: What version of mq is the queue manager running and version of the mq jar files is your application using?

Comment: MQ version is 8 and client jars are version 9.

Comment: Also to add to that, I am using springs cachingconnectionfactory around ibm's MQQueueConnectionFactory

Comment: On the queue manager `SVRCONN` there is a parameter `SHARECNV` that controls the number of sessions that are encapsulated in each MQ channel TCP/IP connection.  The most performance can be gained by setting this to `1`.  IBM states that with the default setting of `10` that the channels are on average 15% slower than setting it to `1`.  So if your goal is to have better throughput then you want to decrease that value.  The spring cachingconnectionfactory should help since starting and stopping the connections to MQ takes times, caching them will help by reusing the connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194240/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-joshmc).