# IBM MQ JMS Connection Pooling and Session Pooling

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

How to implement connection pool in a multithreaded application to produce JMS messages on IBM-MQ?

No of Threads: 15-20
MQ Jar Details: com.ibm.mq.jar
 Name:        WebSphere MQ classes for Java
 Version:     6.0.0.0
 CMVC Level:  j000-L050519.1
 Build Type:  Production

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922339/how-to-pool-the-jms-connection-in-a-standalone-java-application

Comment: As per the Nicholas suggestion "In the absence of anything else, you can use Apache Commons Pool.", I tried to implement connection pool of JMS connections but should I create connection pool or should I create session pool.What should be the best approach to solve the problem of stale connection.